# Criar um efeito de animação que execute apenas umas vez, depois de uma certa altura de rolamento

Tags: jquery, rolamento

Estou tentando criar uma animação para uma div depois que o scroll seja maior de um valor (no meu caso, 1100).

Ele funciona até certo ponto, mas depois que passa de 1100, toda vez que se mexe no scroll este efeito roda novamente.

Eis o meu código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j(window).bind('scroll', function(){
            if($j(this).scrollTop() > 1100)
                $j('.testing')
                    .css("position","fixed")
                    .css("top","10px")
                    .animate({marginTop: '30px'}, 500)
                    .animate({marginTop: '10px'}, 500);
            else
                $j('.testing')
                    .css("position","relative")
                    .css("top","0")
                    .animate({marginTop: '0px'}, 500);
        });
    });
</script>
```

.testing é a minha div e sempre que o scroll passa de 1100 ele executa quase que infinitamente.

A minha intenção é que, quando chegar na altura 1100, ele execute a animação e no fim dela, fique estático com o position fixed até que o scroll seja menor que 1100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode criar uma variável "flag" que guarda o estado da animação para saber de o elemento já foi animado. Pode também comparar a posição do footer na página para voltar a ter `position: absolute` caso ele esteja a chocar com o footer.

Sugestão:

(**Exemplo:** http://jsfiddle.net/px5Ls8q7/)

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    var animationCompleted = false;
    var posicaoFooter = $j('#footer').offset().top;
    var posicaoFinalContent = $j('#content').position().top + $j('#content').outerHeight(
        true);
    var sidebarDiv = $j('.testing');
    $j(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        var scroll = $j(this).scrollTop();
        if (scroll + sidebarDiv.height() >= posicaoFooter) {
            sidebarDiv.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: posicaoFinalContent - sidebarDiv.height()
            })
            return;
        } else if (animationCompleted) {
            sidebarDiv.css("position", "fixed").css('top', '0')
        }
        if (scroll > 1150 && !animationCompleted) {
            sidebarDiv.css("position", "fixed").css('top', '0')
                .animate({
                    marginTop: '-40px'
                }, 100, function() {
                    sidebarDiv.animate({
                        marginTop: '20px'
                    }, 125).animate({
                        marginTop: '0px'
                    }, 150).animate({
                        marginTop: '10px'
                    }, 175);
                })
            animationCompleted = true
        } else if (scroll < 1156 && animationCompleted) {
            animationCompleted = false;
            sidebarDiv.css("position", "relative").stop().animate({
                marginTop: '-30px'
            }, 150).animate({
                marginTop: '15px'
            }, 150).animate({
                marginTop: '-7px'
            }, 150).animate({
                marginTop: '3px'
            }, 150).animate({
                marginTop: '0px'
            }, 150);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Acredito que fiz, mais ou menos, o que explicou, mas acho que fiz algo errado. Editei o post para exclarecer melhor, obrigada.

Comment: @LunaLaura tem algum erro na consola?

Comment: Se você está se referindo ao erro de console na página, não há nenhum.

Comment: @LunaLaura porque é que tem 2x vezes a animação? `.animate({marginTop: '30px'}, 500)`. Pode usar o callback nesta com `30px` e remover a outra linha?

Comment: É por que eu queria fazer um efeito elástico, sabe? ai o marginTop variaria para cima e para baixo para fazer esse efeito, mas eu tentei só com o .animate com o callback e ainda tem o mesmo comportamento.

Comment: @LunaLaura se colocar o seu HTML (ou um jsFiddle) posso colocar um exemplo online com o problema resolvido.

Comment: @LunaLaura estou agora de volta ao computador e acho que tem de mudar o seu `else` para algo como `else if($j(this).scrollTop() <= 1100) $j('.testing')` pois essa nova flag interfere em como o `if` funciona... dê uma olhada aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/dqpqh3y9/

Comment: Esta incrível, mas quando o scroll volta para cima, o efeito para de executar e se usar o scroll para baixo muitas vezes o efeito acontece repetidamente, eu queria fazer com que ele repetisse somente uma vez, depois de atingir certa altura. Poderia me ajudar? Não sei como consertar isso.

Comment: @LunaLaura o que quer que aconteça quando o scroll voltar para cima?

Comment: A ideia é a seguinte: Sempre que chegar a 1100 ele execute o efeito, mesmo fazendo o scroll subir e descer várias vezes.

Para explicar melhor: Gostaria de replicar o efeito da coluna lateral deste [site](http://www.ahnegao.com.br/).

Comment: @LunaLaura então é algo assim que quer: http://jsfiddle.net/ntb9cncn/1/ ?

Comment: desculpa a demora, mas o seu código ficou excelente, só fiz algumas modificações para que ele ficasse como eu queria e funcionou muito bem =)

Olha só o que eu fiz: http://jsfiddle.net/Luna_Laura/qnvspv0y/3/

Não liga pro css, foi só para que você pudesse ver graficamente.

O único problema agora é que eu não consigo fazer com que o  .testing respeite o footer, no caso, não passe por trás ou pela frente.

Queria que quando ele chegasse no limite do footer, ele parasse lá mesmo, como nesse [site] (http://www.ahnegao.com.br/).

Comment: Não está funcionando este código que mandou

Comment: @LunaLaura mas funciona como quer no jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/px5Ls8q7/ ?

Comment: SIM! Perfeito. Vou fazer umas modificações apenas.

Valeu!!

Comment: Oi Sergio, desculpa ter ressucitado o tópico, mas é que eu estava testando o código aqui e descobri um bug... Por algum motivo, o box que fica fixo não respeita o limite, as vezes ele desce demais, as vezes fica mais acima... Tentei muitas coisas aqui mas não consegui, poderia me ajudar?

Obs.: Testei no blog do meu amigo que é [esse](http://www.sodezoeira.com.br), pode verificar o comportamento do box que segue além das páginas (1, 2, 3)... O comportamento varia demais

Comment: @LunaLaura dei uma olhada ao blog e não vejo o problema. Então a box `publi-left contour publi-fixed` fica fixa depois de 2100px e parece-me funcionar bem. Podes explicar melhor o que devo procurar de erro? e que Browser é?

Comment: Eu uso o Chrome, mas observe que o "publi-fixed" não fica na mesma linha do último artigo, as vezes fica mais em cima e as vezes mais em baixo, se puder observar as páginas, vai ver... É isso que eu queria consertar, entende?