# Como fazer efeito 'aparecer' em um elemento de acordo com a rolagem da página?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Vi esse vídeo (link abaixo) e gostaria de construir um elemento que somente aparecesse quando a rolagem atingir o "ponto que toque nele". Creio que deve ser javascript. Se alguém souber ficaria muito grato :D Tentei linkar os arquivos e add a div no meu projeto mas ela simplesmente sumiu.

OBS: Ele mostra o efeito em 3:46

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdgDr_icGdo

Comment: Veja estes posts: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43784 - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26092 - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177112

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a biblioteca [**scrollreveal**](https://github.com/jlmakes/scrollreveal) juntamente com o `jQuery`.

Basta usar:

```
sr.reveal('elemento', options);
```

Segue abaixo um exemplo. *(Basta rolar a página devagar)*

```js
window.sr = ScrollReveal();
sr.reveal('button', {
  origin:'right',
  duration: 1500
});
sr.reveal('.t', {duration: 2500});
```

```css
button {
  margin: 400px 0;
}

.t {
  margin: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>Text</p>
  <button>Ok</button>
  <p class="t">Texto 2</p>
</div>
```

Você pode customizar de várias maneiras, basta escolher as [**opções**](https://github.com/jlmakes/scrollreveal#2-configuration) que vai lhe agrada.

Comment: `sr.reveal` parece um pedaço de diálogo duma peça shakespeareana: sir, revele elemento!, com opções!

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado tá mais para D&D e coisas do tipo, quem sabe pra revelar algum elemento maléfico que está oculto :P

Comment: Coloquei o link dos scripts e alterei os elementos mas não funcionou :( O que será que está acontecendo?

Comment: @LeonardoHenrique você colocou o `jquery` e o `scrollreveal` na respectiva ordem? O seu `script` (onde você define os elementos), está no final da página? Você está adicionando o elemento corretamente (`#id`, `.class` ou `tag`) ? Se possível edita tua pergunta e adiciona como você está fazendo.

Comment: Coloquei o script no final da página como recomendou e funcionou :D Não sabia que tinha posição correta para scripts, sempre coloquei entre o head. Muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 1):

Para esses tipos de efeitos eu recomendo usar jQuery, que já fornece uma gama de facilidades frente ao JS puro.

Se você não tem, basta incluir a biblioteca em sua `<head></head>`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Fiz um pequeno script + CSS onde a única coisa que você precisa fazer é adicionar a classe `.mostrar` ao elemento que você quer *revelar* ao rolar a tela. **Veja:**

```js
$(window).on("load scroll", function(){
   var threshold = 30; // porcentagem da altura visível do elemento que aparecer na tela para iniciar a animação
 $(".mostrar").each(function(){
  var el = $(this);
  var eleHeight = el.outerHeight(); // altura da div
  var eleTopo = el.offset().top; // distancia da div ao topo do documento
  var scrlTopo = $(window).scrollTop(); // quanto foi rolada a janela
  var distance = eleTopo-scrlTopo; // distancia da div ao topo da janela
  var altJanela = window.innerHeight; // altura da janela
  if(distance <= altJanela-(eleHeight/(threshold/10))) {
   el.animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 1200); // 1200 = 1,2 segundo da animação. Quanto menor, mais rápido
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.mostrar{
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Role a tela para baixo</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum condimentum leo vel sem bibendum fringilla. Cras tempor dolor vitae metus dapibus, sit amet placerat nunc iaculis. In cursus velit sit amet orci placerat, a sagittis nisl accumsan. Ut dapibus turpis quis ante interdum euismod. Pellentesque posuere gravida porta. Duis pharetra, diam eu iaculis ornare, lacus sapien pharetra lorem, pulvinar tincidunt diam urna in tellus. Nulla facilisi. Cras in ante vel erat sollicitudin pretium eget in eros. Phasellus ut semper enim. Curabitur cursus mattis nibh ac posuere. Mauris sapien libero, malesuada sed vestibulum eu, ornare eu tortor. Phasellus nec eros a sapien interdum cursus. Sed in nibh feugiat, pellentesque nibh id, mattis mi. Vivamus pretium varius orci, vitae vehicula arcu fermentum id. Praesent non feugiat nibh.</p>
<div class="mostrar" style="display: block; width: 300px; float: left; margin: 20px; background: blue; height: 200px;">
 div 1
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum condimentum leo vel sem bibendum fringilla. Cras tempor dolor vitae metus dapibus, sit amet placerat nunc iaculis. In cursus velit sit amet orci placerat, a sagittis nisl accumsan. Ut dapibus turpis quis ante interdum euismod. Pellentesque posuere gravida porta. Duis pharetra, diam eu iaculis ornare, lacus sapien pharetra lorem, pulvinar tincidunt diam urna in tellus. Nulla facilisi. Cras in ante vel erat sollicitudin pretium eget in eros. Phasellus ut semper enim. Curabitur cursus mattis nibh ac posuere. Mauris sapien libero, malesuada sed vestibulum eu, ornare eu tortor. Phasellus nec eros a sapien interdum cursus. Sed in nibh feugiat, pellentesque nibh id, mattis mi. Vivamus pretium varius orci, vitae vehicula arcu fermentum id. Praesent non feugiat nibh.</p>
<div class="mostrar" style="display: block; width: 400px; float: left; margin: 20px; background: red; height: 200px;">
 div 2
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum condimentum leo vel sem bibendum fringilla. Cras tempor dolor vitae metus dapibus, sit amet placerat nunc iaculis. In cursus velit sit amet orci placerat, a sagittis nisl accumsan. Ut dapibus turpis quis ante interdum euismod. Pellentesque posuere gravida porta. Duis pharetra, diam eu iaculis ornare, lacus sapien pharetra lorem, pulvinar tincidunt diam urna in tellus. Nulla facilisi. Cras in ante vel erat sollicitudin pretium eget in eros. Phasellus ut semper enim. Curabitur cursus mattis nibh ac posuere. Mauris sapien libero, malesuada sed vestibulum eu, ornare eu tortor. Phasellus nec eros a sapien interdum cursus. Sed in nibh feugiat, pellentesque nibh id, mattis mi. Vivamus pretium varius orci, vitae vehicula arcu fermentum id. Praesent non feugiat nibh.</p>
<div class="mostrar" style="display: block; width: 200px; float: right; margin: 20px; background: yellow; height: 200px;">
 div 3
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum condimentum leo vel sem bibendum fringilla. Cras tempor dolor vitae metus dapibus, sit amet placerat nunc iaculis. In cursus velit sit amet orci placerat, a sagittis nisl accumsan. Ut dapibus turpis quis ante interdum euismod. Pellentesque posuere gravida porta. Duis pharetra, diam eu iaculis ornare, lacus sapien pharetra lorem, pulvinar tincidunt diam urna in tellus. Nulla facilisi. Cras in ante vel erat sollicitudin pretium eget in eros. Phasellus ut semper enim. Curabitur cursus mattis nibh ac posuere. Mauris sapien libero, malesuada sed vestibulum eu, ornare eu tortor. Phasellus nec eros a sapien interdum cursus. Sed in nibh feugiat, pellentesque nibh id, mattis mi. Vivamus pretium varius orci, vitae vehicula arcu fermentum id. Praesent non feugiat nibh.</p>
<div class="mostrar" style="display: block; width: 500px; float: left; margin: 20px; background: green; height: 200px;">
 div 4
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum condimentum leo vel sem bibendum fringilla. Cras tempor dolor vitae metus dapibus, sit amet placerat nunc iaculis. In cursus velit sit amet orci placerat, a sagittis nisl accumsan. Ut dapibus turpis quis ante interdum euismod. Pellentesque posuere gravida porta. Duis pharetra, diam eu iaculis ornare, lacus sapien pharetra lorem, pulvinar tincidunt diam urna in tellus. Nulla facilisi. Cras in ante vel erat sollicitudin pretium eget in eros. Phasellus ut semper enim. Curabitur cursus mattis nibh ac posuere. Mauris sapien libero, malesuada sed vestibulum eu, ornare eu tortor. Phasellus nec eros a sapien interdum cursus. Sed in nibh feugiat, pellentesque nibh id, mattis mi. Vivamus pretium varius orci, vitae vehicula arcu fermentum id. Praesent non feugiat nibh.</p>
<div class="mostrar" style="display: block; width: 100px; float: left; margin: 20px; background: gray; height: 200px;">
 div 5
</div>
```